# This object is an integral type. Can I get its value in fewer than five lines of code?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a data reader. I want to compare the value in it with the value 42. I know it is an integral type (e.g., what MySQL calls `INT`, `TINYINT`, `SMALLINT`, `MEDIUMINT`, `BIGINT`, `JUMBODELUXEINT`, etc.). I do not want to hardwire the actual type in to the C# code. The best I have come up with is

```
object x = reader.GetValue(i);
uint k = x is byte ? (byte) x
    : x is short ? (uint) (short) x
    : x is ushort ? (ushort) x
    : x is int ? (int) (int) x
    : (uint) x;
if (k == 42) { ... }
```

This seems incredibly long-winded. I tried using `Equals` but different integral types with the same value do not appear to test as equal.

Is there a better way?

Comment: integral or interger-al?

Comment: Use `uint k = x is uint ? (uint)x : (uint)Convert.ToInt32(x));`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022383/ which expands on Jon Skeet's answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just checking [`Convert.ToUInt32(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ec671dkh.aspx)... yup, it works fine:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Check((byte)10);
        Check((short)10);
        Check((ushort)10);
        Check((int)10);
        Check((uint)10);
    }

    static void Check(object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type {0} converted to UInt32: {1}",
                          o.GetType().Name, Convert.ToUInt32(o));
    }
}
```

In other words, your code can be:

```
object x = reader.GetValue(i);
uint k = Convert.ToUInt32(x);
if (k == 42) { ... }
```

Alternatively, given that all `uint`s are representable as longs, if you're using a data reader could you try `reader.GetInt64(i)`? I don't know offhand whether the conversion will be done for you, but it's probably worth a try.

Comment: Plug in `-10` instead of `10` and watch what happens. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022383

Answer (score 6):

```
if(Convert.ToUInt32(reader.GetValue(i)) == 42) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do Skeet's and Daniel's answers in reverse like this:

```
if (k == Convert.ChangeType(42, k.GetType()) { ... }
```

I haven't tested it though.

Comment: +1 just for being the freak in the room who has to do it opposite! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand you correctly, but I think this should work:

```
int x = int.Parse(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
if(x == 42) { // do your logic }
```

Comment: Converting something to a string and back seems a pretty ugly way of doing a simple numeric conversion, IMO.

Comment: Agreed! though I don't actually know how Convert.ToX works, but i used to think that it has to convert it to a string first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
unit k = Convert.ToUInt32(x);
```

You would be better served renaming your variables, though.  1 letter variables are *sooo last week*.

Comment: This isn't the real code, and there would be no need to have a variable name at all if C# did not have this allergy to comparing numbers to each other... !

Comment: It's the price you pay for using a statically typed language. Neal Ford calls it "bureaucracy."

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
object x = reader.GetValue(i);

uint k;
try
{
    k = Convert.ToUInt32(x);
}
catch(InvalidCastException e) { ... }
if (k == 42) { ... }
```