# Convert unknown boxed simple value types (char, int, ulong, etc.) to UInt64

Tags: c#

Expanding on Jon Skeet's answer to [This Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631994). Skeet doesn't address the failure that occurs when negative values and two's complement values enter the picture.

In short, I want to convert any simple type (held in an unknown boxed `object`) to `System.UInt64` so I can work with the underlying binary representation.

**Why do I want to do this? See the explanation at the bottom.**

The example below shows the cases where `Convert.ToInt64(object)` and `Convert.ToUInt64(object)` both break (`OverflowException`).

There are only two causes for the `OverflowExceptions` below:

1. `-10UL` causes an exception when converting to `Int64` because the negative value casts to `0xfffffffffffffff6` (in the unchecked context), which is a positive number larger than `Int64.MaxValue`. **I want this to convert to `-10L`.**
2. When converting to `UInt64`, signed types holding negative values cause an exception because `-10` is less than `UInt64.MinValue`. **I want these to convert to their true two's complement value (which is `0xffffffffffffffff6`).** Unsigned types don't truly hold the negative value `-10` because it is converted to two's complement in the unchecked context; thus, no exception occurs with unsigned types.

The kludge solution would seem to be conversion to `Int64` followed by an unchecked cast to `UInt64`. This intermediate cast would be easier because only one instance causes an exception for `Int64` versus eight failures when converting directly to `UInt64`.

*Note: The example uses an `unchecked` context only for the purpose of forcing negative values into unsigned types during boxing (which creates a positive two's complement equivalent value). This `unchecked` context is not a part of the problem at hand.*

```cs
using System;

enum DumbEnum { Negative = -10, Positive = 10 };

class Test
{
  static void Main()
  {
    unchecked
    {
      Check((sbyte)10);
      Check((byte)10);
      Check((short)10);
      Check((ushort)10);
      Check((int)10);
      Check((uint)10);
      Check((long)10);
      Check((ulong)10);
      Check((char)'\u000a');
      Check((float)10.1);
      Check((double)10.1);
      Check((bool)true);
      Check((decimal)10);
      Check((DumbEnum)DumbEnum.Positive);

      Check((sbyte)-10);
      Check((byte)-10);
      Check((short)-10);
      Check((ushort)-10);
      Check((int)-10);
      Check((uint)-10);
      Check((long)-10);
      //Check((ulong)-10);   // OverflowException
      Check((float)-10);
      Check((double)-10);
      Check((bool)false);
      Check((decimal)-10);
      Check((DumbEnum)DumbEnum.Negative);

      CheckU((sbyte)10);
      CheckU((byte)10);
      CheckU((short)10);
      CheckU((ushort)10);
      CheckU((int)10);
      CheckU((uint)10);
      CheckU((long)10);
      CheckU((ulong)10);
      CheckU((char)'\u000a');
      CheckU((float)10.1);
      CheckU((double)10.1);
      CheckU((bool)true);
      CheckU((decimal)10);
      CheckU((DumbEnum)DumbEnum.Positive);

      //CheckU((sbyte)-10);  // OverflowException
      CheckU((byte)-10);
      //CheckU((short)-10);  // OverflowException
      CheckU((ushort)-10);
      //CheckU((int)-10);    // OverflowException
      CheckU((uint)-10);
      //CheckU((long)-10);   // OverflowException
      CheckU((ulong)-10);
      //CheckU((float)-10.1);  // OverflowException
      //CheckU((double)-10.1); // OverflowException
      CheckU((bool)false);
      //CheckU((decimal)-10);  // OverflowException
      //CheckU((DumbEnum)DumbEnum.Negative); // OverflowException
    }
  }

  static void Check(object o)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Type {0} converted to Int64: {1}",
                    o.GetType().Name, Convert.ToInt64(o));
  }

  static void CheckU(object o)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Type {0} converted to UInt64: {1}",
                    o.GetType().Name, Convert.ToUInt64(o));
  }
}
```

## WHY?

Why do I want to be able to convert all these value types to and from `UInt64`? Because I have written a class library that converts structs or classes to bit fields packed into a single `UInt64` value.

Example: Consider the `DiffServ` field in every IP packet header, which is composed of a number of binary bit fields:

[image: IP packet DiffServ field]

Using my class library, I can create a struct to represent the DiffServ field. I created a `BitFieldAttribute` which indicates which bits belong where in the binary representation:

```
struct DiffServ : IBitField
{
    [BitField(3,0)]
    public PrecedenceLevel Precedence;

    [BitField(1,3)]
    public bool Delay;

    [BitField(1,4)]
    public bool Throughput;

    [BitField(1,5)]
    public bool Reliability;

    [BitField(1,6)]
    public bool MonetaryCost;
}

enum PrecedenceLevel
{
    Routine, Priority, Immediate, Flash, FlashOverride, CriticEcp,
    InternetworkControl, NetworkControl
}
```

My class library can then convert an instance of this struct to and from its proper binary representation:

```
// Create an arbitrary DiffServe instance.
DiffServ ds = new DiffServ();
ds.Precedence = PrecedenceLevel.Immediate;
ds.Throughput = true;
ds.Reliability = true;

// Convert struct to value.
long dsValue = ds.Pack();

// Create struct from value.
DiffServ ds2 = Unpack<DiffServ>(0x66);
```

To accomplish this, my class library looks for fields/properties decorated with the `BitFieldAttribute`. Getting and setting members retrieves an object containing the boxed value type (int, bool, enum, etc.) Therefore, I need to unbox any value type and convert it to it's bare-bones binary representation so that the bits can be extracted and packed into a `UInt64` value.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want a way to call `Convert.ToInt64` without throwing an exception? If so, it sounds like you want the code in the *question* that Jon Skeet was answering.

Comment: @Gabe Yes, without all the casting and testing. As I stated, one could test for the single special case only and convert as follows: `o is ulong ? (ulong)o : (ulong)Convert.ToInt64(o)`. It would seem getting a simple raw value shouldn't require such a kludge, but in a strongly typed language that may be the simplest answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to post my best solution as fodder for the masses.

These conversions eliminate all exceptions (except for very large `float, double, decimal` values which do not fit in 64-bit integers) when unboxing an unknown simple value type held in `object o`:

```
long l = o is ulong ? (long)(ulong)o : Convert.ToInt64(o));
ulong u = o is ulong ? (ulong)o : (ulong)Convert.ToInt64(o));
```

Any improvements to this will be welcomed.

Comment: Looks good to me. If it does what you want, I'd stick with it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the look. Yes, it works well despite being kludgey... (explanation of what I'm doing added above). It's what you get when you try to twiddle bits in a strong-typed language, I suppose.