# Check if array is null or empty?

Tags: c#

I have some problem with this line of code:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_nameList[index]))
```

What have I done wrong?

EDIT: The m_nameList is underlined with red color in VisualStudio, and it says "the name 'm_nameList' does not exist in the current context"??

EDIT 2: I added some more code

```
    class SeatManager
{
    // Fields
    private readonly int m_totNumOfSeats;

    // Constructor
    public SeatManager(int maxNumOfSeats)
    {
        m_totNumOfSeats = maxNumOfSeats;

        // Create arrays for name and price
        string[] m_nameList = new string[m_totNumOfSeats];
        double[] m_priceList = new double[m_totNumOfSeats];
    }

    public int GetNumReserved()
    {
        int totalAmountReserved = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index <= m_totNumOfSeats; index++)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_nameList[index]))
            {
                totalAmountReserved++;
            }
        }
        return totalAmountReserved;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of problem? Do you get IndexOutOfRangeException?
Post your error

Comment: thats write marlon...take back my comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After Edit2:

You are defining  `m_nameList` as a local variable of the constructor.
The rest of your code needs it as a field:

```
class SeatManager
{       
   // Fields
   private readonly int m_totNumOfSeats;
   private string[] m_nameList;
   private double[] m_priceList;

  // Constructor
  public SeatManager(int maxNumOfSeats)
  {
     m_totNumOfSeats = maxNumOfSeats;

     // Create arrays for name and price
     m_nameList = new string[m_totNumOfSeats];
     m_priceList = new double[m_totNumOfSeats];
  }

  ....
}
```

Comment: Great! I missed that! Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Note that that's only *one* of the problems in the code - see my answer for another.

Answer (score 18):

If `m_nameList` is null, that will still blow up, because it will try to find the element to pass to `String.IsNullOrEmpty`. You'd want:

```
if (m_nameList == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_nameList[index]))
```

That's *also* assuming that `index` is going to be valid if `m_nameList` is non-null.

Of course, this is checking if the *element* of an array is null or empty, or if the array reference itself is null. If you *just* want to check the array itself (as your title suggests) you want:

```
if (m_nameList == null || m_nameList.Length == 0)
```

EDIT: Now we can see your code, there are *two* problems:

- As Henk showed in his answer, you're trying to use a *local* variable when you need a field
- You're *also* going to get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (once you've used a field) due to this:

  ```
  for (int index = 0; index <= m_totNumOfSeats; index++)
  ```

  That will perform `m_totNumOfSeats + 1` iterations because of your bound. You want:

  ```
  for (int index = 0; index < m_totNumOfSeats; index++)
  ```

  Note that `m_nameList[m_totNumOfSeats]` is *not* valid, because array indexes 
  start at 0 in C#. So for an array of 5 elements, the valid indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Another option for your `GetNumReserved` method would be to use:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (string name in m_nameList)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
```

Or using LINQ, it's a one-liner:

```
return m_nameList.Count(string.IsNullOrEmpty);
```

(Are you sure you haven't got it the wrong way round though? I would have thought reservations would be the ones where the name *isn't* null or empty, not the ones where it *is* null or empty.)

If it's the wrong way round, it would be this instead in LINQ:

```
return m_nameList.Count(name => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name));
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment? Bear in mind this answer was written long before the OP included his code...

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes, the code is as it is now the the wrong way raound! I will fix it!

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the error you can perform some pre conditions in the if, like these :

```
if(m_nameList == null || index < 0 || m_nameList.Length < index || String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_nameList[index]))
```

This should works fine(without causing error) in almost any conditions ...

Comment: Nice. Lots of tests there... I count seven? No, eight! Makes me think exceptions sure are wonderful!

Comment: The purpose of this is avoiding the exception, it is not supposed to be faster then get the exception ...

Comment: Yup! All depends on how often it might be happening. If rare, then try/catch is much better (and less testing since there is always a chance something slips through the cracks when you write eight tests in one line). Some times ya gotta avoid the exceptions though... good stuff...

Comment: @KevinP.Rice: I would *never* just let the exception come through and catch it here. An `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception should always indicate a bug, not something deliberate. And I count *four* tests (all OR-ed together, of course), not eight. There are 4 conditions being checked here, and all are valid to check. Were you counting each compound condition as an extra one?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, the three short-circuit ORs perform a test, as well as the `if` statement itself. Though, it can be argued that the `==` and `<` expressions are simple math operations and not tests. Further,  `IsNullOrEmpty` probably wraps several tests. I agree that I would not generally let an exception by here, however, if this were a public method then `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` or `ArgumentNull` could be entirely appropriate. Likewise, for a private method there may be no good reason to test as it would indicate a bug. I'd test if preventing exceptions is needed for non-bug possibilities.

Comment: @KevinP.Rice: I think anyone who *wasn't* trying to get to the maximum possible number here would count this as four conditions. I think given that the title of the question is "Check if array is null or empty?" it's reasonable to assume that the OP really *did* want to perform a check. And sure, letting an exception bubble up might be fine - but that's not what you were suggesting. You were suggesting *catching* the exception: "If rare, then try/catch is much better". I definitely disagree with that. Catching ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or NullReferenceException is simply a bad idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet I grew up writing machine code so I always think about what is *really* generated by "simple looking" code (especially LINQ!) You are correct about try/catch; I'm not sure what I meant late last night! Agree on bubble-up, but a local try/catch is occasionally good to wrap a failure-prone operation such as `HttpRequest`. Might I get your comment on this unrelated question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022383/

Comment: @KevinP.Rice: Not tonight, but I'll mail myself to look into it tomorrow.